# How do I clear the background of a UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am calling a UIImagePickerController to view the albums on the IPhone. The problem seems to be that when the modal slides down on cancel the seems to be a block of white padding at the top of of modal. Does anyone know how to remove this or make it clear?

Here is the code I am using but it is pretty standard.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
//imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of what the white padding looks like]

Comment: no problem with ur code. can you pls add a screenshot of this

Answer (score 1):

From the [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) You **cannot** change the background color.

`UIImagePickerController` is not intended to be modified. If you do, your app will be **rejected** from the app store.

A solution would be to use the  third party libraries like [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20).